# Am I correct to start thinking in terms of "ports" as "networks" or "devices"?

Tags: cisco, layer3

For the longest time, when I would configure a network device I would login to the GUI, and assign it an IP address. As I am getting into Cisco and their ISO model, I am seeing more and more of assigning IP addresses to actual ports and not the device.

In the enterprise world, do devices lose their actual IP address and start to inherit IP addresses assigned to the ports or VLANs so they technically start having several IP addresses assigned to them?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use the word "interface" instead of "port" because a port could be a transport layer address, e.g. TCP port 80 is used by HTTP.

Devices don't really have addresses, the addresses are assigned to the interfaces, either physical or logical interfaces. Routers route between networks, so each router interface needs to be in a different network. For Cisco's IOS, you often create logical interfaces (loopbacks, SVIs, etc.), and you assign addresses to those interfaces. Switches can have addresses assigned to SVIs.

When you use a GUI to assign addresses to a device, you are really assigning an address to a particular interface of the device. I assume you mean something like a home router (off-topic here). A home router will usually have two router interfaces (WAN and LAN), and each of those interfaces get assigned to a different network, and the router routes traffic between the networks. The LAN interface of a home router may be a logical interface to which a switch module and WAP connect inside the chassis.

Answer (score 0):

In networking world there  are different types of IP address

Management ip address

1).This ip address is assigned to device . This ip address is used to access the device

2. Interface assigned ip address are used to configure for actually data flow in networks .